# Shell code- Reading a CSV file by loop and making another one

Tags: linux, shell, awk, zcat

I have to do Shell code that read CSV file line by line, checking every line in some columns values and making another new CSV file according to the conditions.

I've started the code like this:

```
    FileName=$1
    while read line
    do

    zcat FileName awk -F'\t' '$3 ~/.jar/ || $3 ~/.msi/ || $3 ~/.dll/ || $3 ~/.cab/ || $3 ~/.exe/ || $3 ~/.rar/ || $3 ~/.mar/ || $3 ~/.tgz/ || $3 ~/.tar/ ||  $3 ~/.gz/ || $3 ~/.upd/ || $3 ~/.bin/ || $3 ~/.zip/ || $3 ~/.pogo/ || $3 ~/.dcr/ || $3 ~/.qgi/ || $3 ~/.deb/ || $3 ~/.ipa/ || $3 ~/symantec/ || $3 ~/windowsupdate/ || $3 ~/kaspersky/ || $3 ~/adobe.com/ && $42 ~/7/ && $15 ~/androiddownloadmanager/ && $15 ~/.apk/ && $15 ~/.pak/ && $15 ~/.vpx/ {Str="SW Download: " $3;Str>> New.csv} '

    echo "$line" >> new2.csv

    done < FileName
```

Note: The file name is .gz .

(1)I got the error : "syntax error near unexpected token `done'".

(2)I want to check if the new csv will be done and contain lines.

Thanks

Comment: A missing pipe after `zcat Filename` and $ before Filename on the same line? Also, why loop it in shell? why don't you let awk handle the whole file instead of running it for each line? `Filename=$1; zcat $Filename | awk - -`

Comment: Do you really mean that `$15` needs to match those four different regexes at the same time? That's what your code means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the shell loop. Just pipe you `zcat` output to `awk`:

```
FileName=$1

zcat "$FileName" | awk -F'\t' '($3 ~/\.jar/ || /\.msi/ || /\.dll/ || /\.cab/ || /\.exe/ || /\.rar/ || /\.mar/ || /\.tar/ || /\.gz/ || /\.upd/ || /\.bin/ || /\.zip/ || /\.pogo/ || /\.dcr/ || /\.qgi/ || /\.deb/ || /\.ipa/ || /symantec/ || /windowsupdate/ || /kaspersky/ || /adobe\.com/) && $42 ~/7/ && ($15 ~/androiddownloadmanager/ && /\.apk/ && /\.pak/ && /\.vpx/) {Str="SW Download: " $3;print Str > "New.csv"}'
```

And the right syntax to use a variable is `$FileName`, not `FileName`.

**Update:**

As pointed out by tripleee, the `awk` command should be:

```
zcat "$FileName" | awk -F'\t' '($3 ~/\.(jar|msi|dll|cab|exe|rar|mar|tar|gz|upd|bin|zip|.pogo|dcr|qgi|deb|ipa)/ || $3 ~/(symantec|windowsupdate|kaspersky|adobe\.com)/) && $42 ~/7/ && $15 ~/androiddownloadmanager/ && $15 ~/\.apk/ && $15~/\.pak/ && $15~/\.vpx/ {Str="SW Download: " $3;print Str }'
```

Comment: Uh, the syntax here is incorrect. `($3 ~ /\.moo$/ || /\.bar$/)` is equivalent to `$3 ~ /\.moo$/ || $0 ~ /\.bar$/` (notice also how the parens are superfluous). You have to repeat the `$3 ~` or refactor to a single regex `$3 ~ /\.(moo|bar)$/`.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee I updated but keeped the parens as there is a mix of `||` and `&&` here.